# how to deal a case when diffusivity is a function of space and time in heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm looking for a way to get analytical solution of diffusion with time and space-varying diffusivity, i.e.

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} k(x,t)\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$$

where in this case diffusivity $k$ change with space and time.

Is there a way to solve this type of equation in analytical way? I have figured out how to solve it when $k$ is solely a function of time but stucked when $k$ is a space fundtion as welll.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What tells you that the analytic form of solution exists here?

Comment: Doesn it not even exist?

Comment: Well it does not have to be default